# How can i make below javascript code synchronous?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, force.com, jquery, javascript-remoting

Below is the scenario -

```
           $('#registerUser').on('click', function() {
                uploadFile(); 
                var registrationInfo = {
                    "email"             : $('#email').text(),
                    "password"          : $('#password').text(),
                    "confirmPassword"   : $('#confirmPassword').text(),
                    "address"           : $('#address').text(),
                    "religion"          : $('#religion').text(),
                    "motherlanguage"    : $('#motherlanguage').text(),
                    "selectFile"        : $('input[type=file]').val().split('\\').pop(),
                    "familyType"        : $('#familyType').text(),
                    "fileAttachment"    : attachmentBody
                }
                Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                    '{!$RemoteAction.SWASAuthentication.registerMember}',
                    registrationInfo, 
                    function(result, event){
                        if (event.status) {

                        } else if (event.type === 'exception') {

                        } else {

                        }
                    }, 
                    {escape: true}
                );
            });
```

Below is uploadFile  method Code -

```
        function uploadFile() {
            var file = document.getElementById('selectFile').files[0];
            console.log(file);
            if(file != undefined) {
                if(file.size <= maxFileSize) {
                    attachmentName = file.name;
                    var fileReader = new FileReader();
                    fileReader.onloadend = function(e) {
                        attachment = window.btoa(this.result);  //Base 64 encode the file before sending it
                        console.log(attachment);
                        positionIndex=0;
                        fileSize = attachment.length;
                        console.log("Total Attachment Length: " + fileSize);
                        doneUploading = false;
                        if(fileSize < maxStringSize) {
                            attachmentBody = "";
                            if(fileSize <= positionIndex + chunkSize) {
                                attachmentBody = attachment.substring(positionIndex);
                                doneUploading = true;
                            } else {
                                attachmentBody = attachment.substring(positionIndex, positionIndex + chunkSize);
                            }
                        } else {
                            alert("Base 64 Encoded file is too large.  Maximum size is " + maxStringSize + " your file is " + fileSize + ".");
                        }
                    }
                    fileReader.onerror = function(e) {
                        alert("There was an error reading the file.  Please try again.");
                    }
                    fileReader.onabort = function(e) {
                        alert("There was an error reading the file.  Please try again.");
                    }

                    fileReader.readAsBinaryString(file);  //Read the body of the file

                } else {
                    alert("File must be under 4.3 MB in size.  Your file is too large.  Please try again.");
                }
            } else {
                alert("You must choose a file before trying to upload it");
            }
        }
```

In **uploadFile** method i am getting attachmentBody which i will transfer to salesforce apex class and will insert as attachement.

But currently **uploadFile()** below code getting executing before **uploadFile()** finishes its execution.

Please help...

Comment: uploadFile is javascript funciton getting the selected file content

Comment: Generally speaking, uploading is a type of operation that you _don't_ want to be synchronous. If it were synchronous, your user would not be able to interact with the page _at all_ until the upload finished. Instead, I'd point you in the direction of running code that depends on the upload being finished in a callback method that is run after the upload method finishes.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the remoting method as a callback to upload file method:

An example below:

```
var callback = function() {
    // call remoting logic here
    alert('callback function invoked');
}

// call uploadFile
uploadFile(callback);

function uploadFile(customFunction) {
    // get the body
    alert('do Something');

    // call callback to in invoke remoting
    customFunction();
}
```

Refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000415/call-a-function-after-previous-function-is-complete) from stackoverflow for more details.

---

Here is an example in context with your question:

```
$('#registerUser').on('click', function() {

    // include the callback inside a function expression
    var registerMember = function(attachmentBody) {
        var registrationInfo = {
            "email"             : $('#email').text(),
            "password"          : $('#password').text(),
            "confirmPassword"   : $('#confirmPassword').text(),
            "address"           : $('#address').text(),
            "religion"          : $('#religion').text(),
            "motherlanguage"    : $('#motherlanguage').text(),
            "selectFile"        : $('input[type=file]').val().split('\\').pop(),
            "familyType"        : $('#familyType').text(),
            "fileAttachment"    : attachmentBody
        };

        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            '{!$RemoteAction.SWASAuthentication.registerMember}',
            registrationInfo, 
            function(result, event){
                if (event.status) {

                } else if (event.type === 'exception') {

                } else {

                }
            }, 
            {escape: true}
        );
    }

    // call upload file passing the callback function
    uploadFile(registerMember); 

});
```

Upload file would look like this:

```
// upload file method accepts callback method
function uploadFile(registerMember) {
    // when attachment body is not empty, call registerMember
    if(attachmentBody != undefined) {
        // pass the body to callback function
        registerMember(attachmentBody);
    }        
}
```

Comment: I have tried the same as you mentioned, but when i click on registerUser button i am not getting attachment body to pass in apex class.

Comment: I have updated the question can you please validate what i am missing ?

Comment: @NirmallyaGhosh, You were not doing the function call correctly. Updated the answer. with more details.